# How to reset zpool after accidentally disconnecting a drive?

Tags: usb, hard-disk, usb-drive, zfs

I am using OpenZFS on macOS (openzfsonosx.org), on a USB drive. It turns out that if I accidentally disconnect the drive from the computer, then zpool gives errors. However, if I reboot and reconnect, it works fine again.

Does zpool have protection against such disconnection? How can I reset the zpool to normal state after reconnecting the drive, without rebooting?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Please [take the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how Unix & Linux works. Read [how to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: you don't really provide enough detail to answer for sure, but if the drive is just marked as "OFFLINE" in `zpool status`, you can probably just plug it back in and run `zpool reopen pool`, or maybe `zpool online pool devicename`.   See [What is the correct way to recover from ZFS errors after a power failure?](https://superuser.com/questions/1160483/what-is-the-correct-way-to-recover-from-zfs-errors-after-a-power-failure)

Comment: BTW, zfs is pretty resilient and will continue working OK (but far from optimally - and the entire pool and all data on it is at risk if another error were to occur) as long as there is at least one vdev in the pool that isn't in FAULTED state.